# Is there a way to change the view in an entity diagram in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

With so many tables displayed, sometimes it's difficult to find a table diagram I'm looking for.

Shirley there is a better way to find a specific table within a '.edmx' diagram.  (Like switching to a list view or something)

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Model Browser window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738483.aspx).